# How can I fix the error "DynamoDB returns GSI range key not specified errors"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a cloudformation template regarding the dynamodb. I added new index called customerId-index as below:

```
ComponentsTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: ${self:custom.base}-components
    PointInTimeRecoverySpecification:
      PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: True
    StreamSpecification:
      StreamViewType: NEW_IMAGE
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: assetId
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: componentId
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: componentType
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: customerId
        AttributeType: S        
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: componentId
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: assetId
        KeyType: RANGE
    LocalSecondaryIndexes:
      - IndexName: componentType-index
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: componentId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: componentType
            KeyType: RANGE
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: ALL
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
      - IndexName: assetId-index
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: assetId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: componentId
            KeyType: RANGE
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: ALL
      - IndexName: compoentType-gsi
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: componentType
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: componentId
            KeyType: RANGE
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: ALL
      - IndexName: customerId-index
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: customerId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: siteId
            KeyType: RANGE
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: ALL
```

And although I added AttributeName for customerId in AttributeDefinitions, I am still getting the following error:

`ValidationException: Global Secondary Index range key not specified in Attribute Definitions.Type unknown.`

But the specified index range key is and its type already defined as below:

```
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: assetId
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: componentId
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: componentType
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: customerId
        AttributeType: S
```

I wonder if someone can help with the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You have to add the range key, siteId, as well.

Comment: @RobertKossendey actually it is already added and I am still getting the error. I will update the question.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the complete snippet of the CF resource.

Comment: I just deployed the CF snippet you shared and it deployed successfully?

Comment: I also deployed it, worked without issues.

Comment: Yeah, I think this part is working one. I will update with the one which causes an error.

Comment: @N.Olgurizih FYI

Comment: Ok I found the problem. The problem is related to missing customerId. Thanks for your contribution guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- IndexName: customerId-index
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: customerId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: siteId
            KeyType: RANGE
```

Your final index uses siteId which is not defined in the Attribute Definitions. Try below:

```
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: assetId
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: componentId
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: componentType
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: customerId
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: siteId
        AttributeType: S
```

Answer (score 1):

In the updated question there is this Global Secondary Index:

```yaml
      - IndexName: customerId-index
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: customerId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: siteId
            KeyType: RANGE
```

Here, you're referring to `siteId` which is missing from your `AttributeDefinitions` list. You probably want to add something like this:

```yaml
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: siteId
        AttributeType: S
```

DynamoDB needs to know the data types to create Secondary Indexes. That's why you need to ensure all attributes that are used in indexes are specified.